# Some files lost when I add, commit, push and clone again

Tags: android, git, git-clone

I executed these commands on intranet server (initialized empty Git repository in /home/git/project/):

```
mkdir project
cd project
git init --bare
```

Then I executed these commands on client:

```
git clone git@server:project
```

Then copied android source code (directory: `alps/`) to project

```
git status
git add .
git commit -m "xxx"
git push origin master
```

When this operation was done, I deleted the project and cloned it from server again. Some files were lost (e.g.:some `.mk` files in `alps/external/chromium_org`)

Why did it happen?

Comment: Check your .gitignore file if it excludes the missing files

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you've got the `.mk` extension in your `.gitignore` file. The file is in the project root directory. It may be hidden.

If you're sure that you want `.mk` files under source control, find a line with it in the `.gitignore` and delete that line.

Then:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m'removed .mk from .gitignore'
git add --all
git commit -m'tracked .mk files'
```

By the way, a good sample of `.gitignore` for Android can be found in [GitHub default `.gitignore` files](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore).

Comment: @T-Chen better don't use `-f` option. It adds ALL otherwise ignored files which is bad. You will track lots of binary files like compiled classes this way.